# performing linear regression with interaction term (purrr package)

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, broom

I am analyzing the data using `ANCOVA` method and also trying to run several multiple linear regression from the `purrr` package.

The model should be:

`m1 <- lm(PD~SR*Type, data = df` (with interaction term)

`m2 <- lm(PD~SR+Type, data = df` (without interaction term)

My example code

```
library(broom)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(PD=c(10,20,30,40,50,10,20,33,12,52,21,43),
           SR=c(5,10,20,24,6,21,59,22,1,11,12,3),
           n=c("tree1", "tree1", "tree1",
               "tree2", "tree2","tree2", 
               "tree3", "tree3", "tree3",
               "tree4", "tree4","tree4"),
           Type=c("a", "b",'c',
                  "a", "b",'c',
                  "a", "b",'c',
                  "a", "b",'c'))

x <- df %>%
  nest(data = -n) %>% 
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~lm(PD~SR * Type, data= .x)),
         tidied = map(fit, tidy),
         glanced = map(fit, glance),
         augmented = map(fit, augment))

tidy <- x %>% unnest(data) %>% 
  select(n, Type, PD, SR, tidied) %>% 
  unnest(tidied) %>%
  select(n, Type, PD, SR, term, estimate) %>% 
  rename(, species_richness = SR)%>% 
  spread(term, estimate)
```

My problem is that I am expecting the intercept/slope is different to each `Type`.

However, the intercept/slope given by the code is the same for each `Type`.
You can check from `tidy` dataframe.

Any suggestions for this point? I am learning how to use the `purrr` package since it is quite powerfull.

or can u have other methods to do that?

Comment: what output are you getting? When I run your code the created models are different for each group

Comment: the group you are mentioning is the tree right ? I want the output for each type. did u get for the type?

Comment: I already added codes for giving out the results

Comment: `df %>%  nest(data = -n) %>%   mutate(fit = map(data, ~lm(PD~SR * Type, data= .x))) %>% pull(fit)`, I see 4 different models, 1 for each tree type. What does your `tidy` table look ike

Comment: @missuse oh sorry, I just checked the model again. I think I was wrong. The result was correct like you said. But the thing I was expecting should come from the fitted value. It means that I have to predict those models to get the predicted values. Do you think so?

Comment: to get the predicted values its best to provide a nested df with new data for each tree type, and then after getting the predictions unnest on that df

Comment: I already got the predicted values by using `df %>% unnest(data) %>% group_by(n) %>%
  do(modelr::add_predictions(., first(.$fit)))`. However, do you know how to get the uper and lower CI by using `add_predictions` function?